# Soap Request with Apache Camel

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel

i have a wsdl file hosted on a site (which i can't share), and i want to invoke a soap request through apache-camel framework.
I created a maven project, and used the component apache-cxf to compile the .wsdl file and i got all the .java files.
Now i defined a CamelContext and a RouteBuilder to send request, but i am not sure if i understand the flow.

This is my CamelContext:

```
/**
 * A Camel Application
 */
public class MainApp {

    private static final long DURATION_MILIS = 1000;
    /**
     * A main() so we can easily run these routing rules in our IDE
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.addRoutes(new MyRouteBuilder());
        System.out.println("================== STARTING ==================");
        camelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(DURATION_MILIS);
        System.out.println("================== CLOSING ==================");
        camelContext.stop();
    }

}
```

This is my RouteBuilder:

```
    import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
    import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.message.CxfConstants;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    @Component
    public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
     @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
         from("timer://start?repeatCount=1")
        .setBody(constant("11"))
        .bean(NumberToWordsRequestBuilder.class)
        .log("OPERATION_NAME: "+CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME)
        .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, constant("NumberToWords"))
        .log("OPERATION_NAMESPACE: "+CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE)
        .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE, constant("http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/"))
         .to("cxf:bean:cxfConvertTemp")
        //or you can use .to("cxf://someAddress[?options]")
    
        // You can retrieve fields from the response using the Simple language
        .log("The title is: ${body[0].book.title}")
    
        .to("mock:output");
        
        }
   }
```

My CxfEndpoint class:

```
import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.apache.test.NumberConversion.NumberConversionSoapType;

@Configuration
public class CxfBeans {  
    @Bean(name = "cxfConvertTemp")
    public CxfEndpoint buildCxfEndpoint() {
        CxfEndpoint cxf = new CxfEndpoint();
        cxf.setAddress("https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso");
        cxf.setServiceClass(NumberConversionSoapType.class);
        cxf.setWsdlURL("https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?WSDL");
        return cxf;
    }
}
```

What i am not understanding, is that the .wsdl is hosted on a site but all the tutorial use as cxf-endpoint localhost.
Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using spring? Or just a java app? Are you familiar with beans?

@Value() - shall be used for injecting data from application.properties.
Define your String URL like

```java
String WSDL_URL = "YOUR_URL".
```

Or just put address into your bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class CxfBeans {  
    @Bean(name = "cxfConvertTemp")
    public CxfEndpoint buildCxfEndpoint() {
        CxfEndpoint cxf = new CxfEndpoint();
        cxf.setAddress("YOUR URL STRING");
        cxf.setServiceClass(TempConverterEndpoint.class);
        cxf.setWsdlURL("YOUR URL STRING");
        return cxf;
    }
}
```

Also make your route annotated with @Component.

```java
@Componet
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
 @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
     from("timer://start?repeatCount=1")
    .setBody(constant("11"))
    .bean(NumberToWordsRequestBuilder.class)
    .log("OPERATION_NAME: "+CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME)
    .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, constant("NumberToWords"))
    .log("OPERATION_NAMESPACE: "+CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE)
    .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE, constant("http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/"))
     .to("cxf:bean:cxfConvertTemp")
    //or you can use .to("cxf://someAddress[?options]")

    // You can retrieve fields from the response using the Simple language
    .log("The title is: ${body[0].book.title}")

    .to("mock:output");            
    }

}
```

Comment: I have updated my code in the first comment, anyway i am getting the same error "Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[cxf:bean:cxfConvertTemp] <<< in route: Route(route1)[From[timer://start?repeatCount=1] -> [SetBody[... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:cxfConvertTemp due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: cxfConvertTemp of type: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint" .
My project is a Maven project, i'm not familiar with Beans, thanks for you answer!

Comment: so, this is a conversion issue. Smth wrong with your logic. The main issue of your question is now solved

Comment: i don't know if you can answer in this topic, but i want to know if with my actual code i should see the response of the soap request. I'm trying with my WSDL, and before i got the error regarding to the parameters, and now i fixed it. The script looks like is running without any error (only warnings) and i set the log level to info and with the function ".log("The title is: ${body}")" i do not see any values for the var body, i just get "The title is:"

Answer (score 0):

You can use defined bean instead:

```
@Configuration
public class CxfBeans {
    @Value("${endpoint.wsdl}") //url will be defined in application.properties - your wsdl url address (not localhost)
    private String SOAP_URL;
    
    @Bean(name = "cxfConvertTemp")
    public CxfEndpoint buildCxfEndpoint() {
        CxfEndpoint cxf = new CxfEndpoint();
        cxf.setAddress(SOAP_URL);
//service class of your wsdl
        cxf.setServiceClass(TempConverterEndpoint.class);
        return cxf;
    }
    
}
```

and after use it in the route:

```java
 .to("cxf:bean:cxfConvertTemp")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see a reference to application.properties file, but i do not have this.

Comment: You can directly write the url

Comment: You can see my changes into first post, i have defined the CxfBeans class but i get the following error: Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:cxfConvertTemp due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: cxfConvertTemp of type: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:975)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:857)
 at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.resolveEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:124)